# TerraForm AWS: Is it possible to Import all AWS Resources in one time? | terraform import all services in one time

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

currently I started to work on an old AWS Infrastructure and tried to get know all current service states thru "terraform import" separately, but I would like to import with terraform all service in one time to save time and be sure that I have all aws services.

So is it possible to import all AWS Resources in one time?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Meer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my is it possible to import all AWS Resources in one time?

Not directly with TF. But you could use a third-party, opensourced tool, called [Former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) which can generate TF code from existing resources:

> Generate CloudFormation / **Terraform** / Troposphere templates from your **existing** AWS resources

Comment: Is it save? They don't have any security for the credentials...

Comment: @Meer You can host it yourself, if you prefer to have full control.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this recently myself and I would highly recommend [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer).

> A CLI tool that generates tf/json and tfstate files based on existing
> infrastructure (reverse Terraform).

It supports quite a lot of [Terraform providers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/tree/master/providers). I just tested it for AWS and it works like a charm. ;)